# How to change the file upload directory on version 3.5?

Tags: options, uploads, user-interface

The option to change the upload folder for images is gone on version 3.5, any way to make it visible again or a workaround ?

From this [core ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21720):

> Changing the `upload_path` and `upload_url_path` options are pretty dangerous. They have the potential to break quite a bit of things, not to mention they have the potential of simply not working.
>   [...]
>   There's really no good reason to show `upload_path` or `upload_url_path` in the UI unless the values are other than the default (`wp-content/uploads` or '' for `upload_path`, and '' for `upload_url_path`). With that, most of a section disappears, leaving just *year/month* folder organization.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what Joseph suggested, you can also define the upload path in the `wp-config.php` file like this:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'files' );
```

If you'd like it outside the `wp-content` folder, specify path like this:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'uploads' );
```

For uploading to a folder like `example.com/images`, use this code:

```
//Custom upload path
define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'images' );
```

Comment: Leo, can you in your answer include an example ? I will like to have the images uploaded to: example.com/images . Thanks

Comment: @user983248 I've updated my answer.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `''.'images'`, which is just appending `'images'` to an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it at `/wp-admin/options.php`, which lists all options alphabetically. It'll be near the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename your `uploads` directory in two ways:

1. by defining the new directory name on your `wp-config.php`
2. by writing a small function to change the directory dynamically.

Here I explained both the ways. Just take a look at here. Also you can rename `wp-content` directory.

- [Rename wp-content Folder and Uploads - WordPress](http://kvcodes.com/2013/12/rename-wp-content-folder-and-uploads-wordpress/)